# ASP.NET MVC redirect OnEnd

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I am trying to redirect when in method Session_OnEnd() in Global.asax

If I type

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.es");
}
```

And go to Google but when I try this onEnd...

```
public void Session_OnEnd()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.es");
}
```

Shows

> "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code", Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

Anyone helps me with this please??

Comment: How you are testing Session_OnEnd?

Comment: But looks like no accepted answer there..

Comment: @ssilas777 That doesn't necessarily mean there isn't a correct or valid answer.

Comment: have you read the page event life cycle of ASP.NET? (similar applied to MVC...)

Comment: I set the session expiration on 1 minute, to try this, I put a break point on the method start of Session_OnStart and Session_OnEnd, and try Redirect in both, only run in OnStart, in OnEnd not works

Comment: Anyhow I like to redirect when session is end, only this,..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how Session_OnEnd() occurs.  This happens when the session times out, which typically means the user has no active connection for a period of time.   Since there is no active connection, there is no active request, therefor you cannot redirect anyone.

What I think you're trying to do is redirect the users browser when the session times out, and there is no way to do that from the server.  You have to do this in JavaScript on the client after a timeout period of inactivity.

Comment: Yes Erik, I am trying just this, but, what is the form to make this? Any example? Thanks

Comment: May be good idea to mention that for persistent session state providers the Session_OnEnd does not fire at all...

Comment: @David91 - I would suggest asking a different question, as that one is JavaScript based and has nothing to do with MVC or server side.

Comment: @David91- that would be different duplicate :) Basically `setTimeout(20*60*1000, function(){location = "logout.aspx"})` is a reasonable starting point.